# Is cloudfraction a proper measure of gaseous data expanse?

Tags: weather-satellites

I was working with SO2 column data product from https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/OMSO2_003/summary?keywords=OMI%20Total%20Column%201-Orbit%20L2%20Swath
I wanted to know, is the cloudfraction data in SO2 column an accurate measure of the Sulphur Dioxide present in an area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, cloud fraction is not a good measure of $\ce{SO_2}$. Clouds are functions of moisture, temperature, and cloud condensation nuclei. Som of the other variables, such as (but not limited to) `ColumnAmountSO2` or `ColumnAmountSO2_TRL`are better indicators.